# Why does the insert method never get called?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, fold

This code compiles but the `Environment.insert` is never called. I'm sure there is an `envrionmentForm` there.

```
//isauth version of save
  def save(SystemId: Long) = IsAuthenticated { username => implicit request =>
    User.findByEmail(username).map { user => 
      System.findById(SystemId).map { system => 

      environmentForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => BadRequest(html.env_views.createForm(formWithErrors, system, Person.options, user)),
      env => {
        Environment.insert(env)
        Application.Home.flashing("success" -> "Environment %s has been created".format(env.env_name))
      }
    )
    }.getOrElse(Forbidden)
    }.getOrElse(Forbidden)
  }
```

Comment: You may debug to see variables(or println), and you can rewrite use for-comprehension ```for { u <- User.findXXX; s <- System.findXXX } yield {} ```

Comment: but i want to know whats in environmentForm and therefore why Environment.insert is never called

Comment: can you post your `environmentForm`'s code?

Comment: I'd try to use a debugger or simply add logging (play.api.Play.Logger) to see whether you do get a form that has no errors, and then also logging inside Envrionment.insert.  Its possible that whatever insert is doing has a silent error inside, but I can't give a good answer without knowing more about the code.